# What does `fromPublicKey` mean?

Tags: transactions, transfer

I got the below from this [article](https://www.0xdev.co/how-to-transfer-tokens-on-solana-javascript/). What does `fromPublicKey` mean? Who's public key is it? The sender's wallet?

```
const transaction = new SolanaWeb3.Transaction().add(
    createTransferInstruction( // imported from '@solana/spl-token'
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromPublicKey,
        parseInt(amount * Math.pow(10, 6)), // tokens have 6 decimals of precision so your amount needs to have the same
        [],
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID // imported from '@solana/spl-token'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, `fromPublicKey` means the sender's wallet. And actully, the instruction is token transfer, it would be the token associated account that holding tokens cooresponding `fromTokenAccount`
(you can see the solana cook book, https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/accounts.html#facts)